# Does ArrayFire have a bounding-rect function like OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, arrayfire

I'm wanting to generate an approximate bounding rectangle around a binary image using ArrayFire. Basically, what OpenCV's boundingRect() function does. However, I don't see a similar function in ArrayFire. Is there a simple way to achieve this?